# Hide iOS 10 notification on lock screen

Tags: ios, swift, ios10

I have a situation where I want to get iOS 10 notification data (from dictionary),but I don't want to display any notification on the lock screen.

Any solution? Is this possible ?

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *)
{
     let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
     content.body = "Test"

     var userInfo = [String:String]()
     userInfo["identifier"] = Identifier as String
     userInfo["Time"] = DateString as String
     content.userInfo = userInfo
}
```

I want to get data from dictionary but it shows alert notification on lock screen.

```
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger.init(dateMatchingComponents: components, repeats: false)
let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: "hello", content: content, trigger: trigger)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this thing by sending `Silent Push Notification` to your device.

To get silent push notification,

You've to set `content-available` flag to 1 in your push notification payload.

Silent push notifications won't be shown on your lock screen.